# SMART parameters monitoring, can Windows 10 do it on its own?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, monitoring

Is there a way in Windows 10 to read/monitor HDD SMART parameters without relying on external apps? (if not, is it because of SMART licensing?)

Comment: About SMART [reliability](https://serverfault.com/questions/519726/how-reliable-is-hdd-smart-data)

Comment: You've asked several questions in one, but why Microsoft doesn't include it isn't something we can answer.  So you might want to edit the question to limit it to how to do it in Win 10.  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/close/700852?filter-closereason=toobroad)

Comment: ok, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Windows has SMART built in, albeit very crude, as it only gets the status.

Open a command prompt and type `wmic` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then type `diskdrive get status` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type `exit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to leave the wmic prompt

3rd party tools are better as they give far more information

SMART is an industry [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Standards_and_implementation) and there is no licensing.

Comment: Hmm.. my question was more into understanding if Windows 10 offered a casual-user way to monitor SMART parameters *equivalent to what external apps provide* (i.e. no scripting needed, automatically receive notifications for when particular conditions arise, ...). Also, I specifically asked about parameters, not just the overall status. But thanks.

Comment: What third party tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

SMART support in Windows is very basic. I suggest using https://www.smartmontools.org instead.

Specifically, `smartctl` can be used to perform SMART tasks. This is a nice GUI for it: https://github.com/ashaduri/gsmartcontrol.

For constant monitoring, use `smartd`. Here's a WebUI for it: https://github.com/AnalogJ/scrutiny.